# in pycharm, how to jump to the next SEVERE error? (F2 find style warnings)

Tags: pycharm

in pycharm, if I press F2, it jumps to any kind of "Error", e.g. style, english-spelling, spacing (shown as light-red underline), and real errors.

Sometimes I only want to skip directly to the real show-stopper(s), and fix them directly (shown as RED underline)

Is it possible?

I did not find way to specify only "bad errors" in the key-mapping.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make Pycharm go to high-priority problems first:

Go to `Preferences | Editor | General`  and scroll down to `Error highlighting` where you can activate `'Next Error' goes to high priority...`  (Pycharm 4).

If this option is activated, when there is no errors (red), `F2` will loop through warnings (yellow), and finally when nothing serious's left, the typos.

If needs be, typing `error highlighting` in the `Preferences` search box should help finding it.

Comment: If you want to navigate to warnings, and not just errors, right click the Validation Side Bar, and choose "go to next problem". http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html

Comment: It looks as if it _is_ the default behaviour nowadays.